# Way to bind a variable to a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I was wondering if there is a way to 'listen' to a list constantly in Tkinter, if its length gets below a certain threshold a function is called to fill it up again.

Very similar to the way an event is handled for a button etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "fill it up again"?  What does this have to do with tkinter?

Comment: @TimRoberts I am asking if there is a way to setup an event-listener for a variable in Tkinter, like it has for widgets

Comment: IIUC, a simple way would be to wrap the list in another object with an interface close enough to make it a simple drop in in your code but having a length control in its modification methods.

Comment: Certainly not through Tkinter.  It doesn't know anything about Python variables.  A self-monitoring class is possible, but where does "fill it up" come from?  Why don't you just replace every item you take out?

Comment: @TimRoberts I am not adding everytime because i am calling an api to fetch the data, so the application hangs while fetching the data, maybe multithreading is the way to go

Comment: I **think** what OP means is: "How can I set up my Tkinter code so that it receives an event if the length of a list drops below a threshold?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by Martin is also correct.

There is no way to listen to a variable in Tkinter, so I had to go with creating a separate thread which checks the list's size and fetches data if its below a certain limit, while the main application is running.

This vastly improved the performance of my application.

Answer (score 3):

It's not tkinter thing, but you can make an own list class that automatically fills spaces when it gets too short or removes elements if it gets too long. You just need to adjust the list methods:

```
class MyList(list):
    def append(self,element):
        super().append(element)
        if len(self)>10:
            print("Now, the list is too long. Removing the first element")
            self.pop(0)

    def remove(self,element):
        super().remove(element)
        if len(self)<5:
            print("Now, the list is too short. Adding padding zeroes")
            while len(self)<5:
                self.append(0)

    def pop(self,index):
        super().pop(index)
        if len(self)<5:
            print("Now, the list is too short. Adding padding zeroes")
            while len(self)<5:
                self.append(0)
```

So, if you have this class, you can define a list and add and remove elements without it ever getting longer than 10 elements or shorter than 5:

```
a = MyList([1,2,3])
print(a)

for i in range(9):
    a.append(i)
    print(a)

for i in range(9):
    a.pop(0)
    print(a)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 0, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Now, the list is too long. Removing the first element
[2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
Now, the list is too long. Removing the first element
[3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
Now, the list is too short. Adding padding zeroes
[5, 6, 7, 8, 0]
Now, the list is too short. Adding padding zeroes
[6, 7, 8, 0, 0]
Now, the list is too short. Adding padding zeroes
[7, 8, 0, 0, 0]
Now, the list is too short. Adding padding zeroes
[8, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

You can, of course, omit the print statement once it does exactly what you want. But the principle should work.